# Проблема с сохранением файла в Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

После редактирования файла, сохраняю его **ctrl+s** или через **Автосохранение**, закрываю файл, и если открыть данный файл, то продолжает работать **отмена последнего совершенного действия** (ctrl+z и ctrl+y). Подскажите пожалуйста как отключить данную функцию? До обновления Vscode такого не было.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"files.restoreUndoStack": false,
```

Comment: Помогло, спасибо